# How to run .Net project as part of jenkins job in Docker

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, asp.net-core

I am working on continuous integration of a .net project using jenkins. By far, i am able to set a jenkins job in window. But now i need to replicate this all in jenkins running as docker container. I am able to start jenkins in docker, using github as source repository but when i try to build this project, it fails. My project is using asp.net core so i am assuming it should run on linux as well (which is the OS of docker virtual machine).
What i am missing here? Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: maybe describe the commands you perform in your jenkins job

Comment: i tried to use MSBuild plugin in jenkin to build my solution. Following is part of console output : Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
Executing the command msbuild.exe AspNetCore.sln from /var/jenkins_home/workspace/TestAspNetCore
[TestAspNetCore] $ msbuild.exe AspNetCore.sln
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Answer (score 2):

I'm working on a project with .Net core and we started to use Jenkins in Docker container, so far the only way I found was to create a custom Jenkins image. This is my docker file:

```
FROM jenkins
USER root

# Work around https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/1582 until Docker releases a
# fix (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/20818). This workaround allows
# the container to be run with the default seccomp Docker settings by avoiding
# the restart_syscall made by LTTng which causes a failed assertion.
ENV LTTNG_UST_REGISTER_TIMEOUT 0

# Install .NET CLI dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libc6 \
        libcurl3 \
        libgcc1 \
        libgssapi-krb5-2 \
        libicu52 \
        liblttng-ust0 \
        libssl1.0.0 \
        libstdc++6 \
        libunwind8 \
        libuuid1 \
        zlib1g \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install .NET Core SDK
ENV DOTNET_SDK_VERSION 1.0.0-preview2-003131
ENV DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/preview/Binaries/$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION/dotnet-dev-debian-x64.$DOTNET_SDK_VERSION.tar.gz

RUN curl -SL $DOTNET_SDK_DOWNLOAD_URL --output dotnet.tar.gz \
    && mkdir -p /usr/share/dotnet \
    && tar -zxf dotnet.tar.gz -C /usr/share/dotnet \
    && rm dotnet.tar.gz \
    && ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet

# Trigger the population of the local package cache
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE skip
RUN mkdir warmup \
    && cd warmup \
    && dotnet new \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf warmup \
    && rm -rf /tmp/NuGetScratch

USER jenkins
```

I'm still looking for a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The Jenikins task should invoke `dotnet` commands to build. MSBuild is not yet supported for `dotnet`.

Basically, it has to do something similar to what we do in [KoreBuild](https://github.com/aspnet/korebuild):

1. dotnet restore
2. dotnet build / dotnet publish
3. dotnet test

etc

Comment: I tried dotnet build and receiving error output :  [TestMono] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson1233862377010940298.sh
+ dotnet build
/tmp/hudson1233862377010940298.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson1233862377010940298.sh: dotnet: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: You have to install dotnet and add it to the PATH as part of your build step

Comment: I have downloaded dotnet CLI and its working in virtual machine but when i am trying to execute the same from jenkins job, i am getting error :Failed to create prime the NuGet cache. restore failed with: 1. It's like none of the dependency was resolved. Can you please suggest something?